# Mini profile preview of users in the form of popup upon mouse hover

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Why not display small amounts of information of user's profile upon mouse hover?

Comment: What information do you feel would be relevant, when viewed from a question or answer?

Comment: The information is two clicks away, what benefit do you gain from having it in an onhover popup?

Comment: They already do, for users over a certain reputation...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta profile picture, maybe about location, description/job title, last time active/status

Comment: @slugster well, simply the benefit of being informed about a user if reliable or not?

Comment: @jmort253 oh, now that's interesting. sorry everyone! I'm a noob here. just registered yesterday. have mercy ;)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is sort of already implemented. All users who have at least 1,000 reputation on graduated sites (and 750 on beta sites) has the privileges of an [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

These users can see vote counts, and they also gain an expanded user card. Simply mouseover the profiles of any of these users, and the card expands to show more information.